# Extract date value using SSIS derived column

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a file named  `Name_Excaa_2021-11-28.xlsx` and I want to extract only the date value 2021-11-28 using a derived column.

I am using the expression below, but it gives me the output `2021-11-28.xlsx`

```
RIGHT((DT_STR,50,1252)@[User::FileName],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileName]),"_",1) - 1)
```

How can I solve this and get the date value `2021-11-28`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your file names always end with the format `yyyy-mm-dd.xlsx` you can just select that part using `right` to grab the last 15 characters and then extract just the 10 characters of the date from those 15 characters using `left`:

```
left(right(@[User::FileName],15),10)
```

Comment: I only changed the last characters to 16, and it works perfectly.  left(right(@[User::FileName],16),10)